# is there a way to have object instances on mongo schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been doing back end for a hospital prescription management and I used mongo and node for that.. when using the mongo schema, not knowing how many drugs will the doctor write I have to manually write all the drugs for the schema.. so is there a way to automate it .. am new to mongo so help me please.

```
const presmod = mongoose.Schema({
    HospName : {
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    DoctorId: {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    PatientName : {
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    PatientId : {
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    drugs : {
        drug1 : {date:{type: Date, required: true},Name: {type: String, required: true}},
        drug2 : {date:{type: Date, required: true},Name: {type: String, required: true}},
        drug3 : {date:{type: Date, required: true},Name: {type: String, required: true}},
        drug4 : {date:{type: Date, required: true},Name: {type: String, required: true}},
        drug5 : {date:{type: Date, required: true},Name: {type: String, required: true}},
        drug6 : {date:{type: Date, required: true},Name: {type: String, required: true}},
    },
    
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("prescription", presmod)
```

instead of manually typing drug 1, drug 2 ... drug n ,.. is there a way to automate it?

Comment: use [arrays?](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays)

Comment: yeah but how to add the subivisions their name and date?

Comment: why not make a new model for drugs? that seems to be much cleaner.

Comment: the thing is even if i make a new one the number of drugs to be specified is unknown.. and i dont want to hard code

Comment: even though if i created another model i have the same prroblem of typing those drug1,drug2.. drugn manually.. i need a variable or object kind..

Answer (score 0):

using [array](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) you can define it like this:

```
drugs: [{
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  Name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}]
```

Comment: no it wont work.. this will create seperate drug name and dates.. there wont be any connection between drug name and date